# Getting a 404 on images uploaded using FTP in Magento

Tags: php, magento, caching

I have recently installed Magento and am using it for the first time. I am trying to uplaod an image to a folder as the new logo in the heading. When I upload the image using FTP the file uploads successfully but I can’t see it in the folder listing in a browser or on the website or if I visit the url for the image. I get a 404 page instead. Everything is getting cached I believe. I have turned off caching in the back end and cleaned out var/cache folder. This is a new one to me as I wouldn’t ahve thoughts ftp uploading an image would or could be cached? I can’t even change the header image on my website.

Im using the hellowired them as a starting point.

Cheers

Comment: What are the public permissions on the uploaded images?

Comment: Thanks. See comments below.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the problem can no longer be reproduced; it was caused by OP uploading files to the wrong server.

Answer (score 1):

Check the permissions on the Images and the directory it is in.
Can you verify that it is in the folder that you have uploaded it too?
Can you view it on server browsing the directories?
Finally check that you have type it correctly as Linux box's are CAPS sensitive, this could be why you can't see it also.

Comment: I have set the permissions to 777 for the folder and image. Something weird is going on with my ftp application or maybe the server. I thought I would take a screen shot of the ftp location and upload it to another site on the same hosting to show you all but I am getting the same problem there as with the Magento site. I can see the file in the ftp program but not through a browser. Even if I view the folder contents through a browser the image I just uploaded isn't shown.

Comment: The group and owner of the image I just uploaded is the same as images that are in the folder that I can navigate to through a browser.

Comment: Glad you got there in the end. I hope my answer of process of elimination helped you in getting to your answer. If so please mark as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like my host migrated my accounts to another server and I was actually updating the old hosting. Thanks for your help.